# Can I have fglrx's screen brightness settings and xorg's stable Chrome GPU processing at once?

Tags: drivers, graphics, screen, fglrx, function-keys

**THE GENESIS**

I have been using `fglrx-updates` - `VESA:HONDO` (AMD graphics drivers) for some time but Chrome GPU process kept crashing (it was sand-boxed). Therefore now I'm on `xorg` - `Gallium 0.4 on AMD PALM` drivers which very nicely proved to be friends with Chrome.

Actually this would interest everybody having these GPU crashes and for stability I recommend `xorg` instead of `fglrx`. No crashes at all :) .

---

**THE PROBLEM**

But now I can not set brightness level by using special `fn` function keys on my notebook. Ubuntu receives request and displays the change but that is strict formal. I don't know about other settings for that, so I'm always on full-eyes-melting-sun-level-brightness setting.

```
Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on HP 655
Processor: AMD E2-1800 APU
Graphics: Radeon HD 7340
```

---

**EVEN MORE**

Tried also `fglrx` build on my own Ubuntu, very long time spent on preparing, debugging etc.; finally get it to build and install but again had Chrome GPU process crashing...

**What does not work:**

- edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (adding `Option "RegistryDwords"`) & reboot
- change brightness via `xbacklight -set x%`
- manage special keys via `xdotool`

Comment: Now I'm confused because `screen saver` CAN fade the brightness from full to null, but `fn keys` can NOT while displaying the updated level of brittleness...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally this is what has worked**

1. Open / edit grub file `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. Find the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
3. Comment that line (add <kbd>#</kbd> at the begginging) as a backup.
4. Add below the new line containing our settings for brightness management:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_backlight=vendor"`
5. Save the file.
6. Run at the terminal `sudo update-grub` which applies new settings for further system start-ups.
7. Reboot & it's ready to go.

---

Yaaay! No more eyes melting for me...

Now I can adjust the screen brightness via special notebook <kbd>fn</kbd> keys.